# Solving a second order ODE with BVP4c with a vector input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, boundary-value-problem

I wish to solve the second order ODE

$$\frac{\partial ^2 c}{\partial x^2} = kn(x)c(x)$$ using BVP4C in MATLAB. As usual, I decomposed it in to two first order ODEs. I think my problem lies with the fact that I'm trying to pass the known vector as a parameter in to bvp4c. My code is as follows;

```
function ConcBVP = CellConcBVP(space_steps,n,s,c_bound,Diff,K_c)
xmesh = linspace(0,1,space_steps);
solinit = bvpinit(xmesh, @guess);
sol = bvp4c(@(x,y)bvpfcn(x,y,n,K_c,Diff,s), @(ya,yb)bcfcn(ya,yb,c_bound), solinit);
ConcBVP = sol.x;
function dydx = bvpfcn(y,n,K_c,Diff,s)
dydx = [y(2)
        -K_c*s^2*y(1)*n/Diff];
end 

function res = bcfcn(ya,yb,c_bound)
res = [ya(2)
       yb(1) - c_bound];
end
function g = guess(x)
g = [sin(x)
     cos(x)];
end
```

and when I run my code I just get the errors

```
Error using bvparguments (line 108)
Error in calling BVP4C(ODEFUN,BCFUN,SOLINIT):
The derivative function ODEFUN should return a column vector of length 2.
```

Comment: It would help as a first step if the parameter lists of function declaration and function call match. There is a leading `x` that is once there once missing in `bvpfcn`. Next it would help if you gave the types/sizes of all the arguments, you probably will have to use interpolation at some place.

Comment: `dydx` should be a 2x1 vector, but it isn't (that's exactly what the error message tells you). So you need to work out why by checking the variables in the `dydx` calculation, `K_c`, `n`, `y(2)` etc. and make sure they're all scalars giving the correct result.